# Making a more elegant for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a row of six buttons on a web page. Each button makes an image appear elsewhere on the page. Click button one, and image number one appears. Click button two to replace image number one with a transparent (invisible) png and make image number two appear. And so on.

If it sounds like an image gallery, it is indeed very similar.

My script works fine, but I suspect it's not efficient or elegant because I've attached a bulky function to each button. Would a for loop do the job better?

Here's the javascript for the first button. This is repeated six times :-(

```
function swapSegment1() {
var image = document.getElementById("img1")
image.src = "images/frag1a.png"
var image2 = document.getElementById("img2")
image2.src = "images/frag2b.png"
var image3 = document.getElementById("img3")
image3.src = "images/frag3b.png"
var image4 = document.getElementById("img4")
image4.src = "images/frag4b.png"
var image5 = document.getElementById("img5")
image5.src = "images/frag5b.png"
var image6 = document.getElementById("img6")
image6.src = "images/frag6b.png"
}
```

frag1a.png is a visible image. frag2b, frag3b etc are invisible images.

I hope this is clear. Please probe for clarity if needed...

Comment: Recommend putting a pared-down, but complete example in the question (even if it's a bit long) and also putting a copy of that on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net so people can get a better idea of what you're talking about. Also, you said *"frag2b, frag3b etc are invisible images"* -- rather than showing invisible images in the `img` elements, why not *hide* the `img` elements?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with strings you can easily append a number:

```
function swapSegment(index) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (index == i)
      document.getElementById("img" + i).src = "images/frag" + i + "a.png";
    else
      document.getElementById("img" + i).src = "images/frag" + i + "b.png";
  }
}
```

This could be reduced even further, but hey, this is still readable.

Answer (score 2):

With no loops but using recursion:

```
function swapSegment(i){
    var img = document.getElementById('img' + i);
    img.src = 'images/frag' + i + (i > 1 ? 'b':'a') + '.png';
    --i && swapSegment(i);
}
swapSegment(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function swapSegment1() {
    var image = document.getElementById("img1");
    image.src = "images/frag1a.png";
    for (var i = 2; i <= 6; ++i) {
        image = document.getElementById("img" + i);
        image.src = "images/frag" + i + "b.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses the ternary operator for the a/b logic

```
function swapSegment1()
{
    for (var i = 1; 1 < 6; i++)
    {
        (document.getElementById) ('img' + i).src = 'images/frag' + i + (i === 1 ? 'a' : 'b');

    }
}
```